# Why does C language not support column major array?

Tags: c

Is it only a random design choice or is there any specific reason that C supports row-major not column-major? I know that Fortran uses column major. So what is  the reason(if any) behind these design choices?

Comment: Well it had to be one or the other, so why not _row-major_?

Comment: Why does Fortran not support row major?

Comment: Why does your code need column major? (You can probably be just as memory efficient by transposing your algorithm...)

Comment: Perhaps the authors wished to get certain benefits from one approach over the other for their own work: "Equivalently, in row-major order the rightmost indices vary faster as one steps through consecutive memory locations, while in column-major order the leftmost indices vary faster." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: @Tomas, my code does not need column major.I was just curious about these design choices.

Comment: It does support both since your can interpret your array both ways. The array of array construct just lean towards a row major interpretation when **initializing** the array (see @cubbi answer).

Answer (score 8):

Basing my answer on some of the comments to the question as well as some other answers (and some of my own reflections - but notably no knowledge whatsoever of the C language design process...), I believe this is a choice based on merely what the people making this decision (Ritchie?) needed themselves.

If you interpret the indices of a multidimensional array as matrix indices, it makes sense to have the first index as a row index and the second as a column index - i.e. a column-major structure. If your applications are going to be heavy on linear algebra or other matrix-heavy computations, it also makes sense to store these structures in a way that makes it efficient to traverse them one column at a time, since many algorithms do this. For this reason, programming languages such as Matlab and Fortran benefit from being column-major - it makes it easier to write efficient code with matrices and matrix algorithms in mind.

C, on the other hand, is much more general-purpose than e.g. Matlab or Fortran. If you're not going to use `int**` specifically for *matrices*, it doesn't really matter which index is which. And it seems natural that if `a` is an `int**`, then `a[2]` returns an `int*` and `a[2][1]` returns an `int` - you "dig deeper" into the multidimensional array. For efficiency, we now only care that if we pick out `a[2]` and want to iterate it, it should be cached efficiently. *It doesn't matter if you, the programmer, are associating `a[2]` with a matrix row or a matrix column - we're not working with matrices!*

Thus, there is no strong case (that I can make out off the top of my head) for C to be column-major. At the time of implementing the first versions, it might just have been *easier* to make it row-major - perhaps because the underlying low-level language (assembler?) was already row-major - and that was that.

Comment: Bottom line: Fortran focuses on math, and column-major layout makes implementing linear algebra elegant, while C focuses on low-level-ness, and "row-major" layout makes its specification elegant.

Comment: Also note that `int[][]` and `int**` are different.

Comment: @Tinctorius: That's a very nice way to summarize what I'm trying to say. Guess I'm too tired to word it that elegantly =) Regarding `int[][]` and `int**`, I'm well aware that they're not exactly the same thing. For this example, though, I didn't think it really mattered.

Comment: I think it does matter, in a way. `int[n][m]` is much like a dense matrix, and `k[i][j]` dereferences by taking the `(i*m+j)`-th `int`-sized cell. `int**` is a pointer to a pointer, so `[i][j]` involves dereferencing two pointers. The latter has nothing to do with row- or column-major-ness, but the former is exactly what row-major (or: major in the first index, rather than the last) means.

Comment: I think the first sentence in your second paragraph is wrong, I'm pretty sure that describes a row-major regime.

Answer (score 2):

In C array elements are guaranteed to be contiguous memory elements, and a 2 dimensional array is an array of arrays, so say for an array `int a[10][20]`; `a[0]` is itself an array, and its elements must be contiguous. Equally `a[0]` is contiguous with `a[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

C only defines arrays and allows elements of an array to be, in turn, arrays also. For an array of arrays, the first index selects an array element and the second index selects a value element in that array. To have their meaning reversed would create an illogical grammar.

Interpreting the first index as the row number and the second index as the column number to some 2D matrix data structure is just that, an interpretation.

Note that Fortran's (column-major) arrays aren't indexed by applying two individual index operators.

EDIT: To give an authoritative quote, the C standard says, in §6.5.2.1 (C99), after explaining how the result of subscripting a multidimensional array is an n-1-dimensional array

> **It follows from this** that arrays are stored in row-major order

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Right, but that doesn't answer anything.

Comment: It does. When writing  int y[4][3] = { 1, 3, 5,  2, 4, 6,  3, 5, 7 };  We have a canonical description of a 4x3 matrix whose row 0 is 1, 3, 5.