# Is there any way to store a matrix column-major in C or any alternative method?

Tags: c, gcc, matrix, clang, simd

In C, a matrix is stored in [row-major order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716125/accessing-elements-of-a-matrix-row-wise-versus-column-wise). It's a standard usage. Some languages such as FORTRAN store matrices in column-major order. Sometimes, it helps to access matrices in column order, in my programs. So is there any way to force C to store a matrix in column order?

If not, I've done this with intrinsics and gather instruction that can read from columns and the performance is good in Skylake. But I don't want to rely on intrinsics. Because of, portability and compatibility issues. Does gcc/clang generate gather instructions in `-O3` optimization level? I cannot see if compilers use it for auto-vectorizing. I test many programs and simulated the concept but auto-vectorizer don't understand to use gather operation.

I'm using gcc and Clang on Linux.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160943/column-major-array-storage-in-c-compilers) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201679/why-does-c-language-not-support-column-major-array)

Comment: How can you tell column from rows and column-major storing from the other way? What I am going with this is thast you could just swap the sizes of the array dimensions.

Comment: That's because C only has arrays, A matrix is an array of arrays, One way is to change your point of view on the matrix. Another is emulation of x-y addressing in a 1D array..

Comment: Thanks, people. I saw the links, It seems I shouldn't use this method. But, does gcc/clang generate gather instructions? for this purpose, I use AVX2-gather instructions and performance is very good on Skylake. but I can not realize why compilers don't use it for auto-vectorizing

Comment: No, but 2D arrays in C are problematic anyway, and usually you want a 1D array which you address "manually". So it is then easy to swap conventions if, for example, you want to interoperate with Fortran.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: Sorry, but that is nonsense. 2D arrays are no problem at all. The only problem are people who think something like `int **` is a 2D array or can point to one.

Comment: In C89 the syntax for passing 2D arrays about is unacceptable.

Comment: Both are correct, I like 2D arrays. But, sometimes I need to work with pointers. I think both are amazing.

Comment: @FackedDeveloper, If your implementation works with gather try to generalize it. As I know you should generate indices for every read and write. simply use some specific functions to read from columns, etc. For example `__m256i vec = _mm256_read_column_epi32(&mem);`, etc

Comment: Why don't you just transpose the matrix?

Comment: TRANSPOSE is a fortran 90 intrinsic, and there are gcc/gfortran compilers. With ISO_C_BINDING it should be easy to link it with c.

Comment: @EOF Because if I transpose, I should transpose it again for other parts